# Difference between students' vs students

Tags: grammar, possessives, plural-forms

I'm having difficulty understanding when to use students' vs students. I  know you use students' when you're talking about more than one student. For example: "The students' homeworks were marked". However, when can you use students? Are they interchangeable. Could somebody tell me whether the following sentences is correct:

> "Outside my formal education, I enjoy teaching and I’ve been tutoring students in A-Level Mathematics since starting my degree. Additionally, ... I started a scheme intended to help first year university **students’** in their studies."

Answer (score 4):

This is an example of English using the "apostrophe s" to signify possession. Basically:

> student — singular noun: "The student did well on the exam."
>
> students — plural noun: "The students did well on their exams."
>
> student's — singular possessive adjective: "The student's performance was excellent."
>
> students' — plural possessive adjective: "The students' exam scores were all fantastic!"

Adding the apostrophe s to a noun turns that noun into a possessive adjective, and it signifies that the noun it modifies belongs to the noun you used to form the possessive adjective.

If there is a book, and that book belongs to Jane, we can say that it is "Jane's book."

So, your corrected example should not have an apostrophe s in the final sentence.

To read more about apostrophes in English, you can look [here](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/apostro.asp).

Comment: So is the sentence correct: "Helping students progress above their expected grades has been an extremely rewarding aspect of my work" ? I'm a maths undergraduate planning to write a personal statement so you can imagine how bad my English is.

Comment: Grammatically it is correct. Stylistically, I would do some rephrasing. "...progress above their expected grades" sounds a little strange. I would recommend just saying, "Helping students improve..."

Answer (score 0):

> For example: "The students' homeworks were marked"

Note: homework is a non-count noun, and is used with a singular verb. My homework was marked. Bill's homework was marked. The students' homework was marked. Everyone's homework was marked.